# Javascript not working in html file

Tags: javascript, html

I have written code for a basic registration page to run on my webserver but javascript doesn't seem to be working in the html file. I do a form post with a javascript function to find errors but it seems to be completely ignoring the javascript code when I test it. Is there a problem with my javascript code or in the html code? My code is shown below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">

    function checkPasswordMatch(){
        var password = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;

        if(password != password2){
            document.getElementById("divcheckpasswordmatch").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match!";}
        else{
            document.getElementById("divcheckpasswordmatch").innerHTML = "Passwords match.";}
    }

//  $(document).ready(function(){
//      $("#pass2").keyup(checkPasswordMatch);
//  })

    function Error() {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        if(user=""){
            document.form1.username.focus();
            document.getElementById("usernameerror").innerHTML = "Enter username.";
            return false;
        }
        if(pass1=""){
            document.form1.password1.focus();
            document.getElementById("passworderror1").innerHTML = "Enter password.";
            return false;
        }
        if(pass2=""){
            document.form1.password2.focus();
            document.getElementById("passworderror2").innerHTML = "Enter password.";
            return false;
        }
        if(email=""){
            document.form1.useremail.focus();
            document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML = "Enter email";
            return false;
        }

    }

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="link">
    <a href="/" align="right">Home</a>
    <a align="right" href="signin">Sign-in</a>
    </div>

    <div id="header">
    <center><h1><i>IMGCAPTURE</i></h1></center>
    </div>

    <div id="create">
    <center><h2>Create Your Account</h2></center>

<form name="form1" action="account" onsubmit="return Error()" method="POST">
    <div id="username"><center><h3>Enter Username:  <input type="text" name="username" id="user" cols="15" rows="1"></input></h3></center></div>
    <div id="usernameerror"></div>
    <div id="password"><center><h3>Enter Password:  <input type="password" name="password1" id="pass1" cols="15" rows="1"></input></h3></center></div>
    <div id="passworderror1"></div>
    <div id="confirmpassword"><center><h3>Re-Enter Password:  <input type="password" name="password2" id="pass2" onChange="checkPasswordMatch()" cols="15" rows="1"></input></h3></center></div>
    <div id="passworderror2"></div>
    <div class="registrationFormAlert" id="divcheckpasswordmatch"></div>
    <center><h3>Enter Email:  <input type="email" name="useremail" id="email" cols="15" rows="1">
    </input></h3></center>
    <div id="emailerror"></div>
    <center><input type="submit" value="Create Account" onclick="Error()"></input></center>
</form>

    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: try putting your <script> tag at the end, just before your closing body tag

Comment: Why should he do that?  The script block is in the head, where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you are not calling the functions you are creating. So since you are not calling those functions with arguments, nothing inside them is going to happen. Let me know if this fixes it.

Also, stylistically you would want the Javascript code at the end of the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of binding your input `name="password2"` to the function by the `onChange`-tag, try binding it like this:

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[name="checkPasswordMatch"]', checkPasswordMatch);

function checkPasswordMatch() {
    ...
}
```

And in your HTML, remove the `onChange` tag:

```
<div id="confirmpassword">
<center>
<h3>
    Re-Enter Password:  <input type="password" name="password2"   id="pass2" cols="15" rows="1"></input>
</h3>
</center></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've forgotten to include jQuery. If you use pure JS, it works :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkPasswordMatch() {
        var password = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;

        if (password != password2) {
            document.getElementById("divcheckpasswordmatch").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match!";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("divcheckpasswordmatch").innerHTML = "Passwords match.";
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        document.getElementById("pass2").addEventListener('keyup', checkPasswordMatch);
    });

    function Error() {
        var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
        var pass1 = document.getElementById("pass1").value;
        var pass2 = document.getElementById("pass2").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;

        if (user = "") {
            document.form1.username.focus();
            document.getElementById("usernameerror").innerHTML = "Enter username.";
            return false;
        }
        if (pass1 = "") {
            document.form1.password1.focus();
            document.getElementById("passworderror1").innerHTML = "Enter password.";
            return false;
        }
        if (pass2 = "") {
            document.form1.password2.focus();
            document.getElementById("passworderror2").innerHTML = "Enter password.";
            return false;
        }
        if (email = "") {
            document.form1.useremail.focus();
            document.getElementById("emailerror").innerHTML = "Enter email";
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Where exactly do you see jQuery used? If you mean the comment, well..., it's a comment.

Comment: There : `$(document).ready(` and there `$("#pass2").keyup(`. It's commented but for sure if you don't install event handlers when the DOM is loaded nothing will work in this script.

Comment: Hmm... good point. I guess he's trying to help others to debug it? It would help if the question were more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use == or === in your if statements.  You're assigning user, etc. to an empty string in your if conditionals.

```
    if(user == ""){
        document.form1.username.focus();
        document.getElementById("usernameerror").innerHTML = "Enter username.";
        return false;
    }
```